# Suggestion about config, or class

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use a class like constant in codignator 2.3 , can i make a library(class) for each controller or cofing (class- similar to cofig), because if i want to change any thing like message, then i change only in one file the whole controller messages will change .

Any body sugges me . that which one is better approach .
1- make config-file(load in config file)
2- make a class and load like a library

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using the [Language Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html). Put your messages into an English language and then if you need to change them, you only edit the language file.

Comment: i think your Ans is not so efficient . because question was not about language's ?

Comment: @Hameed - it's a solid answer, you should work on your English so you don't run into any more language barriers.

Comment: ok , in case of message it is correct, but in case of table fields, relevant to controller , i think not a satisfactory .

Comment: Can you explain what isn't satisfactory about it? You are wanting to be able to easily change the values displayed to the end-user. This you can easily do with a Language pack. So rather than hard-coding `username:` into all of your fields you would use the appropriate call to the Language Class which would then display `username:`. If you later on need to change `username:` to `email address:` then you just edit the *one* line in the Language pack and it's all done.